# how to get sum of a column with codeigniter query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to get sum of a column values in mysql table with the codeigniter query as

```
$this->db
     ->query("Select SUM(tb1.amount) from table1 tb1 inner join table2 tb2 on tb2.Id=tb1.Id Where tb2.Status='1'")
     ->result()
```

it give me error as `array to string conversion` I need just a number such  `count(amount) returns number of rows with num_row()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use as =>  `$data['total']`

```
$data = $this->db
     ->query("Select SUM(tb1.amount) as total from table1 tb1 inner join table2 tb2 on tb2.Id=tb1.Id Where tb2.Status='1'")
     ->row_array()
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `select_sum()` function of codeigniter. Try the following code-

```
$query = $this->db->select_sum("tb1.amount")
                  ->from("table1 as tb1")
                  ->join("table2 as tb2","tb1.id = tb2.id") 
                  ->where("tb2.status",1)
                  ->get();
$query = $query->result();
```

**OR**

`$query = $this->db->query('SELECT sum(tb1.amount) FROM table1 as tb1 join table2 as tb2 on tb1.id = tb2.id where tb1.status = 1');
$query = $query->result_array();`

Answer (score 1):

Use `row()` instead of `result` if you want to get a single row.

```
$data = $this->db
     ->query("Select SUM(tb1.amount) as total from table1 tb1 inner join table2 tb2 on tb2.Id=tb1.Id Where tb2.Status='1'")
     ->row()
```

To get the data.

```
echo $data->total;
```